# Merging two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I have this type of data frame, with different columns which have a same pattern in their names :

```
data = data.frame(a= c(1,2,3), a.1 = c(4,5,6), b = c(7,8,9))
```

I want to rbind two columns which have this same pattern so I grape them by a for exemple :

```
a = data[grep( "a", names(data)) ]
```

But I can't rbind them

Any idea(s) ?

Comment: What is your expected output? `rbind` doesn't make sense to me, as that adds *rows* to what appears to be a *column*-centric operation.

Comment: I would like to have 1 columns with rbind(a,a.1)

Comment: So you want `stack(data[grep("a", names(data))])`?

Comment: Or `data.frame(a = do.call("c", data[,grep("a", names(data))]))`

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this - paste(data$a,data$a.1,sep="")?

Comment: @Sotos, your exemple is working with my generated data but not with me real data,

Comment: @AllanCameron thank you its working and i got what i need

Comment: The use of `paste` defies the `numeric` class of the data. cara mathias, if your issue needs numbers and/or it is not otherwise complete, you're going to need to add a bit to your question.